# Inheriting missing keys in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am creating a Python3 dictionary:

```
parents = {
    'parent_0': {
        'f_name': 'john',
        'l_name': 'doe',
        'location': 'New York, NY',
        'birth_month': 'september',
        'nationality': 'france',
        },
    'parent_1': {
        'f_name': 'jane',
        'l_name': '',
        'location': '',
        'birth_month': 'may',
        'nationality': ''
    },

}
```

How can parent_1 inherit the key values for l_name, location and nationality from parent_0?

Comment: Is this a specific case? Or part of a larger problem?

Comment: There are many many ways you could do this. Sharing more about the problem you are solving will probably lead to a much better answer.

Comment: Consider https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap

Comment: The nested dictionary 'parent_1' will have the same values as 'parent_0' for the keys: 'l_name', 'location' and 'nationality'.  The goal of the code is that if a change is made on the 'location' key on parent_0 it will replicate on ton 'parent_1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for key, value in parents['parent_1'].items():
    if not value:
        parents['parent_1'][key] = parents['parent_0'][key]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in parents['parent_1'].keys:
    if parents['parent_1'] == '':
        parents['parent_1'][key] = parents['parent_0'][key]
```

Comment: This will make parent_1 inherit parent_0's values even if it has its own.

Comment: are we sure from the question that that's undesirable? It's not clear to me what the desired output is.

Comment: "_How can parent_1 inherit the key values for l_name, location and nationality from parent_0?_" where OP mentioned those `''` keys only...